# Why does NodeJS download the file instead of holding the web

Tags: node.js, http, web

I am not sure about why there is a difference between Mac OS & Windows.
The problem is, on Windows environment, the Chrome/Edge downloads the NodeJS response instead of just loading the webpage. Whenever I visit "localhost:8081" on Chrome/Edge, it happens again and again. I would like to do it as what MAC OS does, anyone can save me?!
Windows Side Response
[Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp5VG.png)

On MacOS, it does sticking on the browser window.
Any idea for this issue?
***Forgot to mention NodeJs version, MACOS: v10.15.3, WINDOWS: v11.12.0***
Hopefully, the version doesn't matter in this case. :'(
[MacOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIfRj.png)

Thanks!

```
var http = require('http'); 

http.createServer(function (request, response){

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('HelloWorld');

}).listen(8081);

console.log('server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

Comment: This seems to be a windows issue. I tried on linux with firefox, chrome and node v11.12.0 and the content was shown in the browser. Also I started a node server on a linux machine and opened the page on a windows 10 machine with ie and edge. Both browsers open the content as web site. I'm not able to install node on windows to test it

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer! I do agree with you that it is also the problem of windows. :3

Comment: In my case it was an error, I wrote `test/plain` instead of `text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wrote: `'Content-Type': 'test/plain'`, which was causing issue. When I wrote it as `'Content-Type': 'text/plain'`, it worked fine.
You need to kill the server and restart again to see the changes!